# How to start Jupyter notebook in background?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Jupiter notebook using Anaconda. I run it as using `jupyter notebook --no-browser` in command prompt in windows 10. I want to run it as the background so that I don't accidentally close the command prompt. The problem here is, many users of systems accidentally close the command prompt, which affects other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Anaconda navigator.
2. Launch the jupyter notebook from it. It will run as a background process. Even if you close the Anaconda navigator, it works. So when you close the anaconda navigator, it asks do you want to kill the background process, make sure you unselect the checkbox. Check below screenshot. 
   [image]

This method worked well.

Comment: There is always a easier method. I tried it and works also :) Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use START /b, but that will terminate the program when command window is closed. You will need a VBScript to accomplish this. This post show a simple script to accomplish this: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Comment: VBScript is same as windows batch script right? You need to run as service in windows, let me google on that.. thank you for info

Comment: Not really - they are different types of scripts.

Comment: I thought I have a way in Anaconda navigator it self to run in background, but all other ways seems pretty complex